# How to indicate wrapped line?

Tags: vim

In **vim** I am now using **wrap on**. I need to indicate wrapped line by prepending character. I know it is possible - I was using it years ago, but my old .vimrc is lost. Or any other useful indication of wrapped line would be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check [`:h showbreak`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27showbreak%27)

> 'showbreak' 'sbr' string  (default "")
>
> String to put at the start of lines that have been wrapped. Useful
> values are "> " or "+++ ":
> :set showbreak=>\

Answer (score 4):

Interesting :) Why won't you just use line numbers on the left? You'll see when new line starts, because new number appears only on new line, and not on line broken on the screen, no matter how long it is.

```
:set nu
```

Comment: I wrote a small snippet a while back that combined `number` and `showbreak` into a nice solution.  I never tested it too thoroughly but it can be found [here](https://github.com/rson/vimscript-snippets/blob/master/blank_showbreak_numberwidth.vim) if you're curious.